# how do I get coins with hyphenated id from coin gecko? All other coin ids without hyphens seem to work fine

Tags: reactjs

import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

`const CoinPage = () => {
const {id} = useParams([]);
const [coin, setCoin] = useState();

const { currency, symbol } = CryptoState();

const fetchCoin = async () => {
const { data } = await axios.get(SingleCoin(id));

```
setCoin(data);
```

};

useEffect(() => {
fetchCoin();

}, []);`

my api:

`export const SingleCoin = (id) =>` https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${id}`;`

all other coins without hyphen work fine, apart from those with hyphens. Am totally knew and confused